# iPhone does not remember my Android USB host. Keep asking "Allow this device to access photos and videos" instead of showing "Trust this computer"

Tags: android, ios, iphone, linux

I'm developing an android USB host application which read photos from iphone, treat iphone as external MTP/PTP devices when iphone connect to the host via USB.

This app works fine, except that it show the popup message on iphone every time I connect the iphone to the android USB host.

iPhone Keeps Prompting "Allow this device to access photos and videos?", In PC(Windows/Linux/Mac), when iphone connected to the usb host, the popup is "Trust this Computer? Your settings and data will be accessible from this computer when connected", and if I tap Trust, this popup will not show again.

So is this because android or I missed something when doing the USB communication? How can I resolve this issue so that when iPhone connected to my android USB host, "Trust this computer" popup can be shown on iphone and iphone can remember my android USB host?